# How could I search a tag that contain <sup> in a Python beautifulsoup find() call

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm search in one html file using beautifulsoup package in Python. And now I wanna locate the following tag:

```
<b>Particulate Matter (PM <sub>2.5</sub> ) [&#181;/m<sup>3</sup>] level in 2010 was </b>
```

How could I do this?

I've tried to use

```
soup.find(text=re.compile("Particulate Matter"))
```

This returns other tags I don't want. The identical words for this tag is "Particulate Matter", "2.5", "level in 2010"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'b' and
          "Particulate Matter" in tag.text)
```

Comment: It did help. But I met another problem, in your way, it returned the tag for PM10 as well. Is there any way like 
soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'b' and
          "Particulate Matter" in tag.text and
    "2.5" in tag.sub)